AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting union when consuming Kafka Message
Context
I write you this message because I have a deserialization error when consuming a Kafka Topic, raised by  io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.java.
Below are relevant versions used in my Spring JAVA project :
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

Not the latest versions, but the same dependencies are also used for consuming other topics in production and the other consumptions work well.
The Problem
The error is:

Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting union
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:308)
at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:86)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:275)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187)

In the message sent into the topic, all the fields contain a non empty string.
A teamate suggested to add default:"" in each field definition.

{
  "name": "namespace_Fld1",
  "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
  ],
  "default": ""
},


But not sure if it will resolve this issue, because there're no empty fields in the message.
Maybe there a difference in writer's schema
{"type":"record",
"name":"myClassName",
"namespace":"fr.laposte.bdl.bscc.myClassName",
"fields":
[
         {"name":"namespace_Fld1",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld2",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld3",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld4",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld5",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld6",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld7",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld8",
        "type":["string","null"]},
        {"name":"namespace_Fld9",
        "type":["string","null"]}
],
"default":null
}

And here is my reader's schema:
  "type": "record",
  "name": "myClassName",
  "namespace": "fr.laposte.bdl.bscc.myClassName",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "namespace_Fld4",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "namespace_Fld5",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "namespace_Fld7",
      "type": [
        "int",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "namespace_Fld8",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

In reader's schema the order of fields is not the same.
Here I read it could be important : https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#binary_encode_complex
Also previous versions of the schema had been published and then deleted by the team who sends me message.
Questions

Should my reader schema be updated in any way ?
Could there be a problem with Avro cache ?
Should something be done with my AVRO reader'sschema ?

Useful articles about schema registry:

https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-avro-serialization-and-the-schema-registry
https://blog.knoldus.com/error-registering-avro-schema-multiple-schemas-in-one-topic/#schema-compatibility-in-kafka


Is it intended that your reader schema has a type "int" in the union for "namespace_Fld7"? The writer schema has a "string" in the union, and that is not compatible.

Removed kafka tags. You can unittest these schema changes all locally. Kafka always accepts bytes; serialization happens outside of it

Yes, thanks @OscarWestravanHolthe-Kind, I saw that after. Yes I will correct that, and we will test if that was the source of the problem. The error message doesn't mention the int type being a problem, so maybe there is also an another error. But yes, I think I will putting fields in the same order than writer's schema and with same typ

Thanks @OneCricketeer. I'm not sure how to do that. Do you mean I can create my local AVRO writer's schema and send a message to my local machine ? Would you some good examples showing how to do that with Spring/Java ? Or do you mean maybe that we should edit messages in the Kafka instance i.e: https://docs.byteplus.com/api/docs/kafka/editing-and-detaching-tags ? Thanks a lot. Well I assume from your username that you're a big fan of cricket. I played if a few times in India and it was really fun ^^

You don't need to send anything. Avro can operate entirely in memory with both reader and writer. Look at the Avro website

Here is how I fixed my problem.
In my app that receives the KAFKA messages.
I updated my AVRO schema so that all the fields present in the published (by the sender) AVRO schema on the web were also present in the AVRO schema of my receiving application.
I also respected the same order of fields.
And finally, one the field had the wrong type in my receiving app. I changed that.
After all theses fixes, I was able to consume messages without any problems !
Thanks a lot for your answers !
